# Only accept positive values that are equal to or under 100 in C++

Tags: c++

So for what I'm doing I can only accept values that aren't negative and can't be greater than 100. The rest of the program works as planned. I've tried a couple of other things such as using absolute value yet they didn't quite work. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void getScore(double[]);
double calcAverage(double[]); // Make it a double because you want the exact answer not a rounded one
double findLowest(double[]);


void main() {

 double scores[5]; // We want to store 5 answers
 double averageScore, lowestScore;
 getScore(scores); // Collects the Input
 averageScore = calcAverage(scores); // The average
 lowestScore = findLowest(scores); // Finds the lowest score that was put into the array

 cout << "Here are the Results!" << endl;
 cout << "The average score was a: " << averageScore << endl;
 cout << "The lowest score was a : " << lowestScore;
 cout << endl;


 cin.ignore();
 cin.get();

}

void getScore(double scores[])
{
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Will loop 5 times for 5 answers
 {
  cout << "Enter The Test Score Here?:  " << endl;
  cin >> scores[i];// will store the inputs that you enter

  {
   if (i > 100) 
   {
    cout << "Not a valid answer try again";
    cin >> scores[1];
   }
  }
 }
}

double calcAverage(double scores[])
{
 double temp = 0.00; // It's 0.00 because we need decimals

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  temp += scores[i]; // adding the score values to temp
 }
 temp /= 5; // Divides all of the scores by 5 to find the average
 return temp;
}


double findLowest(double scores[])
{
 double temp = 0.00;

 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  temp = scores[i];
  if (scores[i - 1] > scores[i]) {
   scores[i] = scores[i - 1];
   scores[i - 1] = temp;
  }
 }
 temp = scores[0]; // Array starts at the lowest value
 return temp;
}
```

Comment: in `getScore()` you have `if(i > 100)` it should be `if(scores[i] > 100)`

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong

```
if (i > 100) 
{
    cout << "Not a valid answer try again";
    cin >> scores[1];
}
```

First of all, as JackVanier stated, you check for i to be greater then 100 instead of scores[i]. And one more thing: if the user inputs a wrong value again, you accept it, and always on the position 1 in your array. You should ask to re-enter the value until a valid one.

Use this instead:

```
while (scores[i] < 0.0 || scores[i] > 100.0)
{
    cout << "Not a valid value! Enter again: ";
    cin >> scores[i];
}
```

Comment: Good idea to put in a test that `cin` is still valid, handle and ignore if it isn't, to prevent an infinite loop on hopelessly bad input .